# Vim go to function begin

Tags: vim

I want to use `;;` to go to the c language function begin.

ex.

```
void helloworld() {
}

void helloworld2()
{
}
```

If use `[[` it can not jump `helloworld` function, `[M`, `[m`, and `[{` also is not perfect.

So I add nmap in `~/.vimrc`

```
fun! GetFuncBLine()
    let num = search("^[^ \t#/]\\{2}.*[^:]\s*$", 'bW')
endfun
nmap <silent> ;; :call GetFuncBLine() <CR>
```

Use this `;;` , the function begin line can not push to vim jump list, so `CTRL+o` or `CTRL+i` will no use

I'm crazy.

Comment: In your example, where are you when you press `[[`, `[M`, `[m`, or `[{`? What do you get instead of what you want?

Answer (score 0):

.vimrc :

```
fun! JumpFuncName()
  let lnum = line(".")
  execute "normal " . lnum . "G<CR>"
  execute "normal \<C-O>"

  let num = search("^[^ \t#/]\\{2}.*[^:]\s*$", 'bW')
  execute "normal " . num . "G<CR>"
  execute "normal \<C-O>"
endfun
nmap <silent> [[ :call JumpFuncName() <CR>
```